# iPhone / iPad IOS How To Get Framework Bundle Version

Tags: ios, frameworks

Trying to get a .framework 's bundle version.  Tried to find the file using path for resource and then use NSBundle something like...

```
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"SomeFramework" ofType:@"framework"];
    NSBundle *bundle = [[NSBundle alloc] initWithPath:path];
    _version = [bundle objectForInfoDictionaryKey:(NSString *)kCFBundleVersionKey];
```

But path keeps coming back nil......

Better way?

Comment: Because that is just a reference to the framework. Framework is not actually there.

Comment: ok this is a custom framework / bundle ... should have mentioned

Comment: Also, is there a different way to get the bundle version from any framework?

Comment: @ort11 Did you manage to get the framework bundle version? I'm looking for exactly the same.

Comment: Nope, moved on from this problem.

Answer (score 3):

```
NSArray *ar = [NSBundle allFrameworks];

for (NSBundle *b in ar) {

NSLog(@"%@",[b objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"CFBundleName"]);

NSLog(@"%@",[b objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"CFBundleShortVersionString"]);

}
```